# Shooting object until the end of the screen not just until cursor position

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local function shoot( event )

    local x, y = event.x, event.y
    rotateShip(x, y)

    local laser = display.newImage("Images/laser.png")
    laser.x = player.x
    laser.y = player.y
    transition.to(laser, {time=300, x=x, y=y, onComplete=shotDone})

end
```

^ That is my code so far. It shoots the object until it reaches the click position. What I want it to do is continue on past the click until it reaches the edge of the screen. I already have the angle of the shot stored in a variable that for the sake of this we will call "shotAngle"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Liv :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so first of all: you should not do this movement with `transition.to()`. As I assume you make a game where you can shoot laser projectiles. Way easier would be moving all of the projectiles you have currently in game by `velocity*dt` (in their current moving direction) where `dt` is amount of time passed since last frame. Then you can just check if they are out of playground and delete them if yes. But if you really want to do it this way...

Oh boy, here we go!

```
local function shoot(event)
    local width, height -- Size of playground
    local ex, ey = event.x, event.y -- Where player have clicked/tapped/etc
    local px, py = player.x, player.y -- Current position of player
    local speed -- Projectile speed in [pixels per milisecond]

    -- Our laser projectile
    local laser = display.newImage("Images/laser.png")
    laser.x, laser.y = player.x, player.y

    -- Borders: bx, by
    local bx, by = width, height
    if ex < px then
        bx = 0
    end
    if ey < py then
        by = 0
    end

    -- Let's get our target coordinates
    local tx, ty = bx
    ty = ((py-ey)/(px-ex))*bx+py-((py-ey)/(px-ex))*px
    if ty > height or ty < 0 then
        ty = by
        tx = (by-py+((py-ey)/(px-ex))*px)/((py-ey)/(px-ex))
    end

    -- Let's get animation time now!
    local distance = math.sqrt((tx-px)*(tx-px)+(ty-py)*(ty-py))
    local time = distance/speed

    -- Now, just shoot
    transition.to(laser, {time=time, x=tx, y=ty, onComplete=shotDone})
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me so much :)

Comment: When I run it, it says that it can't do the maths because tx is a nil value. I imagine this is because tx is defined as nil and then is still nil unless ty is greater than height.

Comment: @Liv fixed. Should work now in every case, I started writing case in which we need to calculate `tx` and then totally forgot initial one, kek.

Comment: Yep that fixes that problem. Only issue now is when I click on the left hand section of the screen it shoots backwards.

Comment: @Liv What do you mean by *backwards*?

Comment: It shoots out the back of the spaceship that is shooting it rather than the front. You've been so helpful so it's okay if you're busy

Comment: @Liv Nah, it's totally not a problem, I'm curious and another thing is that you still didn't even approve this answer, kek. How about this code? By the way: why you don't want to switch to way easier solution (the one listed at the beginning of the answer)?

Comment: I could do that! I'm new to lua and corona as a whole so I don't really get much of the syntax.

Comment: @Liv Basically Corona should have function that is called each frame. In that function you will make your lasers move and check if they are inside screen. Rest is up to you: where you want to hold lasers, how do you want to store them etc. Did updated code work?

Comment: Yep. Thank you so much :) you've been so helpful!